# Rollup import font and icons files via url plugin make bundle size huge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup

I have react lib built with Rollup

- There is bunch of icoonmoons-icons and some fonts
- When I include font and icons via URL PLUGIN

```
url({
   include: [
     '**/*.woff',
     '**/*.woff2',
     '**/*.eot',
     '**/*.ttf',
     '**/*.svg',
   ],
   limit: Infinity,
}),
```

BUNDLE Size become a huge like 600kb.

I am trying to find a proper way to include this in bundle.

Also If I remove **limit: Infinity,**
Bundle size is reduced on 98kb, but icons are not loaded.

Anyone knows some alternative here?